# how to send form data through javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

HTML code-

```
<form>
....
<a class="art-button" href="edit.php" >Edit</a>
<a class="art-button" href="#" onclick="show_confirm()">Delete</a>
</form>
```

JavaScript-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_confirm()
{
    var r=confirm("Do you want to delete?");
    if (r==true)
      {
      // call "delete.php?id=value"
      }
    else
      {
      //go back to same page
      }
}
```

`how can I call delete.php?id=value` from javascript`

Comment: why is there form tag with anhor tags only?

Comment: Updated my answer in reply to your comment

Comment: Not separating content and logic is so 1990's (you shouldn't use JavaScript as HTML attributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do but the code should be like:

```
<a class="art-button" href="delete.php?id=value" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')">Delete</a>
```

no need to submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.submit()` as HS suggests.

Alternatively, if you want to make this work even when the user has JavaScript turned off (that's not necessarily the case - your decision) make the two links submit buttons:

```
<button type="submit" value="Delete">
```

and add `on_confirm()` to the form's submit event:

```
<form onsubmit="return on_confirm()">
```

and make the function return `false` or `true` depending on the outcome of the confirm():

```
 var r=confirm("Do you want to delete?");
 return r;
```

Comment: but when user clicks on `edit` then?? because both form actions are different can I set the form action in javascript also?

Comment: @amanda "Edit" is not a form action, is it? It's just a link, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript:

```
(document.forms['formname'] || document.formname).submit();
```

Comment: but when user clicks on `edit` then?? because both form actions are different can I set the form action in javascript also?

Answer (score 0):

Give the  and id="formId" (`<form id="formId">`)

```
document.getElementById("formId").submit();
```

For this to work the form needs the url it should submit to.

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" action="delete.php?id=value">
```

### Edit

If you just want a confirm button i'd use pekkas answer (+1)

### Edit in reply to question

You could to:

```
form = document.getElementById("formId")
form.action = "edit.php?id=value";
form.submit();
```

if you want it to submit to different pages.

Comment: but when user clicks on `edit` then?? because both form actions are different can I set the form action in javascript also?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (r==true) {    
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php",
        cache : false,
        data: $("#id_of_form").serialize(), // here will be the values from form
         success: function(msg){
         }
     });
```

and in delete.php you will receive values in $_POST array

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
<form id="randomForm">
    ....
    <a class="art-button" href="edit.php" >Edit</a>
    <a class="art-button" id="deleteLink" href="#" onclick="show_confirm()">Delete</a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#deleteLink").click(function(){
        $("randomForm").submit()
    });
</script>
```

Please note the extra ID tags I have added

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href = "delete.php?id=" + value;`